# Script for finding a longest and shortest word or string in a file?

Tags: bash, scripts, text-processing

I am performing Genomics. I have a file with FASTA format reads. These are genes. Each gene is called a read or contig. Each contig starts with a header and is followed by alphabets or nusleotides eg: ACTG , of specific length. I want to determine the longest contig and the shortest contig or read or gene in that file. Please tell me a ubuntu script to find such contigs. Each contig or read is in this FASTA format is as follows:

```
>Locus_1000_Transcript_1/1_Confidence_0.000_Length_648 FTBs=645 (Header)
CcGccttggtaacctCgccAGcatATtgagcTttGGatccGGaTggtcgtaGaAtgGCaaG
GcaGgagAgAgtgtctaatgtggCgccGctctgtAccCgGgGGgTAACaAtgAATTtGCga
CgaCGtggTAtGcCcttCGttgAaacccTtaTtagttGgAGCcGctAtgtggcgGTccaat
TaTcaagtAttTcCCACaTcttgAagCgcttcTgGATgTacgCatactatgggTtgacgtt
AGtGtAgCcgAgattTCacaGtAgctcCGAACGgtgGTagCAgacGcccGttCacAAaAaC
```

The header has a defined format that shows gene loci and number of genes and there will be space between each contig or read. Each of my read or contig in a file will start with a header of same type as mentioned above, but values may differ. Each contig or read starts with > sign. There may be contigs of same lengths. – Science 3 mins ago

Comment: I notice that there's a space in the header, does the header have a defined format? Also will there ever be spaces in the string which follows your header?

Comment: I have attempted to format your input correctly but please check it (remember that this board will treat the FASTA `>` header symbol as a blockquote markup). IMHO since you're asking about shortest and longest, your sample should include at least two sequences - including any record separator (such as a blank line between sequences) that may assist the parsing.

Comment: Question: are there multiple headers in file or just one ?

Comment: Also, your example, shows contigs of same length.  What if there are two longest or two shortest contigs ? How should that be handled ?

Comment: Thank you all. The header has a defined format that shows gene loci and number of transcripts and there will be space between each contig or read. Each of my read or contig in a file will start with a  header but values may differ. Each contig or read starts with > sign. There may be contigs of same lengths.

Comment: Could you please provide an example that shows input and expected output for records of different lengths?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the `Length` values in the FASTA headers are correct, I would extract them from there:

```
sed -nre 's/^>.*_Length_([0-9]+) .*/\1/p' \
```

then sort them numerically

```
| sort -n \
```

then output the first and last line

```
| sed -ne '1p;$p'
```

In one statement:

```
sed -nre 's/^>.*Length_([0-9]+) .*/\1/p' | sort -n | sed -ne '1p;$p'
```

---

If the lengths declared in the headers cannot be trusted, then to count the length of the FASTA sequences, I would first convert them to [unfasta](https://github.com/zwets/unfasta), then print the line length of every second line into the  same `sort | sed` filter as above:

```
uf | awk 'NR%2==0 {print length}' | sort -n | sed -n '1p;$p'
```

Where `uf` is the simple bash script found [here](https://github.com/zwets/unfasta/blob/master/uf).

---

Note: both one-liners are filters, that is they read their input from standard input and write to standard output.  Use `cat` to feed them files (or `wget -O -` to feed them off the internet).

Answer (score 1):

This python script builds up dictionary of records and uses linear search to find which one is shortest, which one is longest in the file. Note , that this ignores cases where there are two contigs of the same value ( although that can also be implemented.

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
def main():
    records = {}
    current_length = 0
    current_contig = ''
    with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
        for index,line in enumerate(f,1):
            if line == '\n': continue
            if line.startswith('>'):
               if current_contig != line:
                   records[current_contig] = current_length
                   current_contig = line.strip()
                   current_length = 0
            else:
               current_length = current_length + len(line.strip())
    records[current_contig] = current_length
    records.pop('')

    shortest_contig = None
    longest_contig = None 
    longest_val = 0
    shortest_val = float("inf")
    for contig,length in records.items(): 
        if length < shortest_val:
            shortest_val = length
            shortest_contig = contig
        if length > longest_val:
            longest_val = length
            longest_contig = contig
    print('Longest: ' + longest_contig)
    print('Shortest: ' + shortest_contig)


if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

Test run:

```
$ cat input.txt                                                                                                                  
> Entry 1
CcGccttggtaacctCgccAGcatATtgagcTttGGatccGGaTggtcgtaGaAtgGCaaG
GcaGgagAgAgtgtctaatgtggCgccGctctgtAccCgGgGGgTAACaAtgAATTtGCga
CgaCGtggTAtGcCcttCGttgAaacccTtaTtagttGgAGCcGctAtgtggcgGTccaat
TaTcaagtAttTcCCACaTcttgAagCgcttcTgGATgTacgCatactatgggTtgacgtt
AGtGtAgCcgAgattTCacaGtAgctcCGAACGgtgGTagCAgacGcccGttCacAAaAaC

> Entry 2
CcGccttggtaacctCgccAGcatATtgagcTttGGatccGGaTggtcgtaGaAtgGCaaG
GcaGgagAgAgtgtctaatgtggCgccGctctgtAccCgGgGGgTAACaAtgAATTtGCga
CgaCGtggTAtGcCcttCGttgAaacccTtaTtagttGgAGCcGctAtgtggcgGTccaat
TaTcaagtAttTcCCACaTcttgAagCgcttcTgGATgTacgCatactatgggTtgacgtt
AGtGtAgCcgAgattTCacaGtAgctcCGAACGgtgGTagCA
$ python3 contigs.py  input.txt                                                                                                   
Longest: > Entry 1
Shortest: > Entry 2
```

Comment: This is not about line length as far as I understand. One record can span multiple lines until there is a new header starting with `>`.

Comment: @ThomasW. I think you're right. That's what I was guessing in the beginning, but OP provided only limited example.  I'll edit my answer then

Comment: @ThomasW. I've edited my answer , please check

Comment: FASTA is a horribly underspecified format. Every line is either a header (starting with `>`), or part of a sequence following a header. White space in sequences must be stripped before processing. Since the line breaks in sequences are only a _recommendation_, I am surprised that the silly 60/70/72 chars line length is still being used. Maybe it was there so as to not discriminate against users on the less fortunate platforms than ours, where Notepad would probably set the PC on fire for any line beyond 256 chars :-)

Comment: @zwets I thought I did strip whitespaces  from sequences .That's what `current_length = current_length + len(line.strip())
` does.  Or are you just saying in general ?

Comment: @Serg I'm just venting my general peeve with FASTA. :-)